# How to get value on change or on input method in angular2 using bootstrap-colorpicker?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, angular-cli, color-picker

I am using angular-cli and bootstrap-colorpicker. I want to get the value while picking up a color from the colorpicker onchange / oninput  method.

here is my html code:

```
<div id="cp2" class="input-group colorpicker-component">
  <input id="colorInput" type="text" value="#00AABB" class="form-control textedit" data-type="color"  (input)="testevent($event)" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i></i></span>
</div>
```

in ts file:

```
testevent(event){
    console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

This function works when I make an input directly in the input type. Using jQuery method onchange or oninput I am able to get value. But I want to use angular2 way.

Please suggest me to solve this situation.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can use `[(ngModel)]` just as anyother input

```
  <input id="colorInput" type="text" 
     [(ngModel)]="colorCode" 
      value="#00AABB" 
      class="form-control textedit" 
      data-type="color"  (change)="test()" />


test(){
    console.log(this.colorCode);
}
```